# Kernel mode keyboard filter intercept - double output

Tags: c, windows, winapi, kernel, driver

I've edited the WDK ***kbfiltr.c*** callback routine to intercept the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and replace it with 'E'.
It works except that it always replaces it with 2 'E's.
So pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will output 'ee'.
Here's the code:

```
{
PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA pCur = InputDataStart; 

PDEVICE_EXTENSION   devExt;
WDFDEVICE   hDevice;

hDevice = WdfWdmDeviceGetWdfDeviceHandle(DeviceObject);
devExt = FilterGetData(hDevice);

while (pCur < InputDataEnd)
{
ULONG consumed = 0;

if (pCur->MakeCode == 0x01) {//Esc
pCur->MakeCode = 0x12; //E
}
else{
pCur++;
continue;
}

// indicate one packet at a time
(*(PSERVICE_CALLBACK_ROUTINE)(ULONG_PTR) 
devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassService)(
devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassDeviceObject,
pCur,
pCur+1,
&consumed);
pCur++;
}
// tell the caller you consumed everything
*InputDataConsumed = (InputDataEnd-InputDataStart);

(*(PSERVICE_CALLBACK_ROUTINE)(ULONG_PTR) devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassService)(
devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassDeviceObject,
InputDataStart,
InputDataEnd,
InputDataConsumed);
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This is only a guess, but are you getting one for the key press and one for the key release?

Comment: I don't think so because it seems to do it on a key press, and repeatedly when the key is held - as when typing normally.

Comment: Have a look at the definition here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff542337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx I think you need to check the flags to see whether you have a "makecode" or a "breakcode".

Comment: I tried checking the flags by outputting different keys for 'make' and 'break' but it still seems to be doing the same thing.
At this forum a member had what may be a similar issue where the callback routine was called twice, I wonder if that is the problem?
https://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=207941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was coding error.
Changing the code as below seems to make it work.

```
    {
PKEYBOARD_INPUT_DATA pCur = InputDataStart; 

PDEVICE_EXTENSION   devExt;
WDFDEVICE   hDevice;

hDevice = WdfWdmDeviceGetWdfDeviceHandle(DeviceObject);
devExt = FilterGetData(hDevice);

while (pCur < InputDataEnd)
{
ULONG consumed = 0;

if (pCur->MakeCode == 0x01) {//Esc
pCur->MakeCode = 0x12; //E
}

// indicate one packet at a time
(*(PSERVICE_CALLBACK_ROUTINE)(ULONG_PTR) 
devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassService)(
devExt->UpperConnectData.ClassDeviceObject,
pCur,
pCur+1,
&consumed);
pCur++;
}
// tell the caller you consumed everything
*InputDataConsumed = (InputDataEnd-InputDataStart);

}
```